# In google sheets, is there a way to keep certain columns dynamic and remaining as static/fixed?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, primary-key

(i) Col A-J are auto-populated from another sheet using =filter function
(ii) Col K to col P are manual entries filled by me

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ecDy.jpg)

Problem is: sometimes let's say if Row 6 gets deleted in the source sheet, then entire numbering and ordering gets changed in this sheet (destination sheet). This creates problem and the manually filled data in  Col K-P gets out of sequence.

I wish to move data filled in Col K-P alongwith the automatic row movement.

Any other solutions are welcome as well :-)

[Link to google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZkHByPFrkuF4cd90hokOZI0yfMQKXkxBgP3kvs8AKFA/edit#gid=1700194277)

Comment: Can you provide a sample sheet showing the expected result?

Comment: Hi, sure. I have added the sheet link in the above post.